# calling READ a second time gets end-of-file error

Tags: io, fortran

I am trying to read binary data from a file.

```
INTEGER MAX_LAT,MAX_LON,MAX_SHELL,MAX_ORB_PNTS
INTEGER YYYY1,MON1,DD1,HH1,MIN1,DOY1
REAL*8 SEC1

OPEN(20,FILE=INPUTFILE,STATUS='OLD',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
READ(20)MAX_LAT,MAX_LON,MAX_SHELL,MAX_ORB_PNTS
...
READ(20)YYYY1,MON1,DD1,DOY1,HH1,MIN1,SEC1
...
CLOSE(20)
```

In between (where I put '...') I am just doing some byte swapping and printing of the data read.

If I run this code the first READ works fine. So I am sure that the input file is in the right place.
But i get this error for the line of the second READ:

```
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

The data types for my variables are the same as in the programm which wrote the file. Anyway the file is >3000 KB, so I am pretty sure the end of file cant be reaching after reading four integer values.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments below, the problem was endianness. A simple CONVERT='SWAP' in the OPEN statement solved the problem. Thanks for all the help...

Comment: How was the file written? Sequential unformatted access relies on record control words to indicate the end of a record, maybe the complete file is just a single record?

Comment: I think you are right. Suez will have to use direct or stream access, if there are no record delimiters.

Comment: Thats the code for writing the file:
`code`
OPEN(20,FILE=OUTFILE,STATUS='UNKNOWN',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
WRITE(20)MAX_LAT,MAX_LON,MAX_SHELL,MAX_ORB_PNTS
WRITE(20)YYYY1,MON1,DD1,DOY1,HH1,MIN1,SEC1
...
CLOSE(20)
`code`

Comment: @suez Was the file written on the same machine that you're trying to read the data from?

Answer (score 0):

Binary I/O with Fortran can be quite tricky. I suggest you use streams for a more C like behaviour. A nice introduction can be found [here](http://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/streamIO.html).

This page can be summarized as follows:

Writing:

```
OPEN(UNIT=11, FILE="file.name", STATUS="NEW", ACCESS="STREAM")
WRITE(11) your,data1,variables
WRITE(11) more,data2
```

Reading:

```
OPEN(UNIT=22, FILE="file.name", STATUS="OLD", ACCESS="STREAM")
ipos = 1
READ(22,POS=ipos) your,data1,variables
ipos = IPOS + SIZEOF(your) + SIZEOF(data1) + SIZEOF(variables)
READ(22,POS=ipos) more,data2
```

Comment: Yeah, thats one solution. But the thing is that the input files aren't wirtten with acces="stream", so I've got those nasty headers and trailers between my data records.
Surely I could read a header and then read a number of bytes according to the value in the header and skip the trailer. (Thats pretty much what I did in an java programm to read those files.)
But the point is that by using the 'normal' way of reading and writing data you shouldnt need to care about such things, right?

Comment: Oh sorry, I assumed that you had the possibility of changing the way your data was written. Did the writing and reading happen with the same fotran implementation?

Comment: The files were written usind fortran77. I am now writting a program also using fortran77 to read those files. I hope thats what you've asked for.

Comment: I was rather asking about the compiler.

Comment: Also, different endianess could be a problem.

Comment: Right, thats the case. As mentioned I do some byte swapping with the values read, but the read statement doesnt know about that. So its problally returning a wrong header value... any ideas on how to fix this? I've read that some complilers have an option to change endianess. Cant say if my compiler does support this, since i am not at work right now...

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that the error is "end of file" rather than "end of record".   Are you sure that you are opening the correct file?   Have you output the values that you read on the first read to see that they are correct?   If necessary use a hex editor to determine the expected values.

Examine the file with a hex editor and see what the record lengths are and compare to the lengths expected by your reads.   Since written by Fortran, each record will include a pre and post value with the record length, typically 4 bytes.   As hinted by some of the comments, you can figure out what the length of the record length values are in the file and compare to what your current compiler uses, either by writing a test file or checking its documentation.   Some compilers have compile-options to change the length used.  4 bytes is typical but sometimes 8 bytes are used.